# Can DataStudio Community Visualizations access a Chart Palette?

Tags: looker-studio

I am creating a DataStudio community visualization that uses ~12 or more colors and I would like to give users the ability to choose them.

Today, I can define many "FILL_COLOR" [style elements](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/config-reference#styleelement). However, this is redundant to the report chart palette and not arranged as compactly as the chart palette.

Is there a way to access the report theme 'Chart Palette'? Or, is there a way to embed a 'Chart Palette' style element? Thank you.

[image: Custom style with 9 colors] vs
[image: Report Theme Chart Palette]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest version of the [dscc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google/dscc) (0.3.1) provides the theme information in a key called `theme`. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/library-reference#theme_style) shows you how you can access the theme information in a community visualization.